# как настроить отображение значения по адресу в GDB?

Tags: ассемблер, gdb

Вот дизассемблированный код:

```
    0x000055555555576e <+0>:     endbr64 
    0x0000555555555772 <+4>:     push   rbp
    0x0000555555555773 <+5>:     mov    rbp,rsp
    0x0000555555555776 <+8>:     sub    rsp,0x20
    0x000055555555577a <+12>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x14],edi
 => 0x000055555555577d <+15>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x0
    0x0000555555555784 <+22>:    jmp    0x5555555557ac <printDoubleLookNumber+62>
    0x0000555555555786 <+24>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x14]
    0x0000555555555789 <+27>:    and    eax,0x80
    0x000055555555578e <+32>:    test   eax,eax
    0x0000555555555790 <+34>:    je     0x555555555799 <printDoubleLookNumber+43>
    0x0000555555555792 <+36>:    mov    eax,0x31
    0x0000555555555797 <+41>:    jmp    0x55555555579e <printDoubleLookNumber+48>
    0x0000555555555799 <+43>:    mov    eax,0x30
    0x000055555555579e <+48>:    mov    edi,eax
    0x00005555555557a0 <+50>:    call   0x5555555550d0 <putchar@plt>
    0x00005555555557a5 <+55>:    shl    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x14],1
    0x00005555555557a8 <+58>:    add    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x1
    0x00005555555557ac <+62>:    cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x7
    0x00005555555557b0 <+66>:    jle    0x555555555786 <printDoubleLookNumber+24>
    0x00005555555557b2 <+68>:    nop
    0x00005555555557b3 <+69>:    nop
    0x00005555555557b4 <+70>:    leave  
    0x00005555555557b5 <+71>:    ret
```

Выражение `display` выводит только адрес регистра.

Например `display $rbp-0x14` на выходе выдает мне `$rbp-0x14 = (void *) 0x7fffffffdd9c`.

`0x7fffffffdd9c` это адрес который отображается мне отладчиком какждый раз как я перехожу к следующей инструкции. Выглядит это примерно так `1: $rbp-0x14 = (void *) 0x7fffffffdd9c`.

Мне нужно чтобы отображался не сам этот адрес, а значение хранящееся в нем. Как это сделать, чтобы не приходилось на каждой новой инструкции печатать `x/x $rbp-0x14`???

Comment: В руководстве по GDB сказано что можно это сделать с помощью формата `i` и `s`. Но они выводят содержимое в неподходящем для практики формате (нечитабельны).

Comment: Сам вопрос задал - сам на него и ответил) ну может хоть кому да пригодится это.

Answer (score 1):

При использовании команды постоянного отображения `display` используется автоматическое отпределение вывода. Если используется размер элемента(например `b`, `h`, `w` или `g`) то значение будет отображаться так будто было введено через команду `examine` или проще `x/...`, также эта команда будет использоваться если указан формат вывода `i` или `s`, специфичный только для `examine`. Во всех остальных случаях команда `display` отобразит адрес вместо значения по адресу, равно так как это было бы сделано через команду `print` вручную.

Например: `display/xw $rbp-0x14` выведет `x/xw $rbp-0x14  0x7fffffffdd9c:      0x00000008` в моем случае. Так как после самой команды `display` и формата вывода `x` идет спецификатор размера элемента `w`.

Если же не использовать спецификатор размера элемента, то `display` будет выводить адрес. Пример: `display/x $rbp-0x14` выведет `/x $rbp-0x14 = 0x7fffffffdd9c`. Как видно в последнем примере - значение которое писалось после адреса в первом - отсутствует.